# Can I use Apple/Google In app Purchase without paying?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, app-store-connect

I was tasked for creating a prototype of an app for a client with in app purchase (using ionic). I found [this website](https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/) explaining the process.

> The first step is to configure your app and the products you would like to offer on iTunes Connect and Google Play Developer Console.

I don't have either and from what I understood on reading said websites, I need to pay 99$/year for apple and 25$ for google Pay and neither propose a (free) trial version (I only want to test and make it ready for later serious development).

Is it possible to test/use this without paying ? (A trial/student/ version I misssed ?)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is a one time payment when you are going to publish an app in Google Playstore. From [this article](http://www.androidauthority.com/publishing-first-app-play-store-need-know-383572/) you will read everything about this topic.

Also, I can see that you will be using Cordova which considered as 3rd party app. You can [obtain private app publishing right](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/get-started#obtain_private_app_publishing_rights):

> **If the user doesn't have a developer account:**
>
> The user is shown the sign-in screen, where they have an option to
>   create a developer account. After completing the account creation
>   process, including paying a $25 registration fee, the user is given
>   the option to allow your service account to publish apps privately for
>   their organization.
>
> **If the user has a developer account, but isn't signed in to the Play Console:**
>
> The user is shown the sign-in screen. After signing in successfully,
>   they are prompted to select the appropriate developer account (if
>   multiple accounts exist). The user is then given the option to allow
>   your selected service account to publish apps privately for their
>   organization.
>
> **If the user has a developer account and is signed in to the Play Console:**
>
> The user is prompted to select the appropriate developer account (if
>   multiple accounts exist). The user is then given the option to allow
>   your selected service account to publish apps privately for their
>   organization.